# Express-session does not create any session

Tags: mongodb, express, session

Im trying to implement some basic sessions functionality in my toy project with express-session and connect-mongo for session storage.

What i expect:

1. Browser gets cookie after recieving response from server
2. Session data is written to collection "sessions"
3. I get debug messages from express-session in console, because i start the app with `DEBUG=express-session:* nodemon ./bin/www`

What i get instead:

1. Browser never gets cookie
2. No documents are being created in the collection (the collection itself is being created every time i launch the app though)
3. There are no debug messages from express-session in the console

Everything related to DB and session setups in the app.js file:

```
// DB setup
var mongoDB = require('./k'); // K is a file containing connection string
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection Error: '))

// Session setup

const connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: connection,
  collection: 'sessions'
})

app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
  }
}));
```

Is there anything i clould be missing? What could be causing this issue for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongostore')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    store: new MongoStore({'db': 'sessions'})
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was being caused by the order of middleware in my app.js file. I moved the code with DB setup and session setup right above routers and it worked. app.js before:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var entriesRouter = require('./routes/entries')
const categoriesRouter = require('./routes/categories')
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/entries', entriesRouter)
app.use('/categories', categoriesRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


// DB setup
var mongoDB = require('./k'); // K is a file containing connection string
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection Error: '))

// Session setup

const connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: connection,
  collection: 'sessions'
})

app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      secure: false 
  }
}));

module.exports = app;
```

app.js after:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var entriesRouter = require('./routes/entries')
const categoriesRouter = require('./routes/categories')
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



// DB setup
var mongoDB = require('./k'); // K is a file containing connection string
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection Error: '))

// Session setup

const connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: connection,
  collection: 'sessions'
})

app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      secure: false 
  }
}));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/entries', entriesRouter)
app.use('/categories', categoriesRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```